# DVI not working, VGA works fine

Tags: dvi, nvidia-graphics-card

Previously, I had a dual monitor setup, and it was working perfectly with my old PC. Now, I have taken my old, same graphics card and put it into a new PC and while it detects my DVI monitor

[image]

My DVI monitor stays in sleep mode, even when I have it configured in windows to always be on. Any Help?

GPU: nvidia GeForce 210

CPU: AMD Athlon II X4 630

OS: Windows 8, however, it also doesn't work on XP, 7, Ubuntu, or Fedora

Through process of elimination, I've found that it almost definitely isn't an issue with the monitor, cable, or OS, or motherboard settings/problems, and is most likely a card issue.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20359/discussion-on-question-by-user3377520-dvi-not-working-vga-works-fine).